# How to solve $x \geq \frac{y}{z-\ln{x}}$ for positive variables?

Tags: inequality, special-functions

How can you solve $x \geq \frac{y}{z-\ln{x}}$ for $x$ when the variables are real positive values?   I am only really interested in the case where the values are large and $z > \ln x$.

> How can one find a closed form solution for $x$? I am ok with
>   bounds that are out by constant factors.

Maple does not give an answer. For the equality $x =  \frac{y}{z-\ln{x}}$ it gives
$$x = -\frac{y}{\text{LambertW} ( -y e^{-z} )}.$$

I don't really understand this Maple solution as the real values $z = 2\ln{x}$ and $y = x\ln x$ solve the original equation and the denominator in the Maple solution seems to be imaginary.

> Is this Maple solution to the equality correct?

As a note, I believe that $\text{LambertW(n)} \sim \ln(n)$ and also $ \ln{n} \geq \text{LambertW(n)} >\ln/2$ if $n \geq e$ so this might be a useful way to get a bounds in terms of $\ln$.

Comment: whats source of your question ?

Comment: What kind of solution are you expecting?  I don't think you'll be able to get 3 separate inequalities involving only $x$, $y$, and $z$, respectively.  [Here's a plot of the solution set of your inequality](http://i.imgur.com/3f2iQtU.png) for $0 \leq x,y,z \leq 2$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Edited question.

Comment: How big is $y$ compared to $z$?  For example, is $ye^{-z}$ small?

Comment: In my application $ye^{-z}$ is between $\frac{1}{\ln{n}}$ and $\frac{1}{\ln^2{n}}$. The variable $n$ is the total size of the problem  I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $z > \ln x$ and all variables are positive we have

$$
\begin{align}
x \geq \frac{y}{z - \ln x} \quad &\Longleftrightarrow \quad \ln x - z \leq - \frac{y}{x} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \quad x e^{-z} \leq e^{-y/x} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \quad -ye^{-z} \geq - \frac{y}{x} e^{-y/x}.
\end{align}
$$

For the moment let $w = -y/x$, so that the above inequality is $-y e^{-z} \geq w e^w$.   The quantity $w e^w$ has a minimum at $w=-1$ with height $-1/e$, so there are no solutions to your inequality if $-y e^{-z} < -1/e$ or, equivalently, if $y > e^{z-1}$.

Assuming solutions exist, we can solve your inequality using the two real-valued branches of the Lambert $W$ function, $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.  We get

$$
W_{-1}(-ye^{-z}) \leq -\frac{y}{x} \leq W_0(-ye^{-z})
$$

or, equivalently,

$$
- \frac{y}{W_{-1}(-ye^{-z})} \leq x \leq - \frac{y}{W_{0}(-ye^{-z})}
$$

[It is known](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article983.html) that $W_{-1}(x) \leq \ln(-x) - \ln(-\ln(-x))$ for $-1/e \leq x < 0$, which we can use to find a lower bound on $x$.  We find that the lower bound $x \geq -y/W(-ye^{-z})$ is satisfied when

$$
\frac{y}{z-\ln y + \ln(z-\ln y)} \leq x.
$$

By referring to the [asymptotic formula for $W_{-1}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) we can see that the absolute error of this approximation decreases to $0$ as $y e^{-z} \to 0$.

Bounding $x$ above is not as easy.  By the power series expansion of $W_0(z)$ about $z=0$ we know that

$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{W_0(-z)} &= \frac{1}{z} - 1 - \frac{1}{2}z-\frac{2}{3}z^2-\frac{9}{8}z^3-\frac{32}{15}z^4-\frac{625}{144}z^5 - \cdots \\
&= \frac{1}{z} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {c_n} z^n,
\end{align}
$$

which is convergent for $0 < z < 1/e$ and where every coefficient $c_n$ is negative.  To get a lower bound for this we may truncate this series at any point and conclude that

$$
-\frac{1}{W_0(-z)} \geq \frac{1}{z} - \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} {c_n} z^n\right) - 2 c_{N+1} z^{N+1}
$$

for all $z > 0$ small enough.  (*Note the $2$ here is almost arbitrary; the factor only needs to be $>1$ and could probably be chosen to maximize the interval where the bound holds.*)  For example,

$$
-\frac{1}{W_0(-z)} \geq \frac{1}{z} - 1 - z
$$

for $0 < z \leq 0.307$, and thus

$$
- \frac{y}{W_0(-ye^{-z})} \geq e^z - y - y^2 e^{-z}
$$

for $0 \leq y \leq 0.307 e^z$.  The absolute error on this lower bound is $O(y^3 e^{-2z})$.

We conclude that

> For the inequality
>
> $$
> x \geq \frac{y}{z - \ln x}
> $$
>
> to be satisfied it is sufficient to have
>
> $$
> \frac{y}{z-\ln y + \ln(z-\ln y)} \leq x \leq e^z - y - y^2 e^{-z}
> $$
>
> as long as $0 \leq y \leq 0.307 e^z$.

Comment: Thanks. To argue the other way round you get that my inequality implies $x \geq \frac{y}{z-\ln{\frac{y}{z}}}$ I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given $y,z$ and looking for $x$ you won't find it without the Lambert W function or a numeric approach.  A numeric approach will work easily, though.  You can either use a one-dimensional root finder such as in chapter 9 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) or any numerical analysis text, or you can use iteration.  If $x$ is large (and $10$ is getting large, $100$ certainly is), $x$ is much greater than $\ln x$.  Start with $x_0= \frac yz$ and iterate $x_{i+1}=\frac y{z-\ln x_i}$.  It should converge very quickly.  Then if $x_c$ is the convergent, your solution is $x_c \le x\lt \exp(x)$

Comment: Edited the question. But why is the Maple solution imaginary or have I got that wrong?

Comment: I don't know Maple, but Mathematica does that, too. When you pose a problem like this, the program doesn't know whether it is to be solved over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

Comment: What do you get if you tell Mathematica you only want real solutions?

Comment: I've never figured out how

Comment: I think you just specify the domain as Reals. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html